# What can I do when I want to run run ITCase with mvn?

Tags: java, maven

When we run utcase, we can use `mvn test -Dtest=AA`, but if we want to run ITCase, what can we do?

I use `mvn test -Dtest=AAITCase`, but this case will not run.

So when I want to run ITCase, what can we do?

- mvn version: 3.2.5
- Java version: JDK 8

Comment: Running integration tests will be done with maven-failsafe-plugin and not via maven-surefire-plugin ...that means also as already mentioned to run in the integration test phase assuming that you have configured the maven-failsafe-plugin correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration tests will be executed in the `verify`phase, not in the `test phase (see the [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)):

> verify - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met

So you have to call

```
mvn verify -Dtest=AAITCase
```